# Removing duplicates from int[]

Tags: java

New to Java and trying to do some kata. The goal is to write a function that removes duplicate values from an int[], and returns an int[] with duplicates removed and in the same order as they originally were.

I've been stuck for a while now, would anyone be able to help point me in the right direction here? Current progress:

```
import java.util.*;

public class UniqueArray {
  public static int[] unique(int[] integers) {
    // Return integers when duplicates are not possible
    if (integers.length <= 1) {
      return integers;
    }

    ArrayList<Integer> newArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    // Check each word in integers against the new array
    for (int i = 0, j = integers.length; i < j; i++) {
      for (int k = 0, l = newArray.size(); k < l; k++) {

        // If match found, move to next int from integers
        if (integers[i] == newArray.get(k).intValue()) {
          break;
        }

      // If no matches found, add to new array
      newArray.add(integers[k]);
      }
    }

    // Convert ArrayList to int[]
    int[] finalArray = new int[newArray.size()];
    for (int i = 0, s = newArray.size(); i < s; i++) {
      finalArray[i] = newArray.get(i).intValue();
    }

    return finalArray;
  }
}
```

Comment: You're only adding to `newArray` in the newArray-loop, which will execute 0 times the first time, and 0 times every time after that since that's the only place you add to it. Know the flow of your program. Debug. (And fix your indentation, for readability)

Comment: My function is returning an array of length 0, and I'm not sure which part is failing, the part where words get added to newArray, or the part where newArray gets converted to finalArray.

I've been learning this stuff for so many hours my brain is melting but I don't want to walk away from the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The `ArrayList` is empty, so the inner loop won't be executed.

You can follow this logic instead:

- Loop over the integers array.

  - Check if the ArrayList already contains the integer. If it doesn't, add it.

Comment: It's good you did not give the code but textually explain it IMO.

Comment: !!!
How did I not notice that?

Awesome, exactly the answer I was looking for. Thanks!